# Managing massive sensor data within Ada code

Tags: open-source, library, database, api

I'm looking for a database system with these requirements:

1. Native support for **Ada code**.
2. Easy to store **sensor data**. I'm managing about ten sensors with a
   sampling frequency or 1Hz, so I have about 1 **million samples** per
   day.
3. I wish I had that data **available to other applications**: like rrdttol
   in order to generate graphs, logging, etc.
4. **Single access** is enough, because I will use a protected object.
5. It is a **personal project** so I'm looking for free personal use
   libraries/databases.

Do you know any database system (RRD, levelDB, Redis..) with an easy interface/library to code that in Ada?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt there are any databases (and even more so for database systems) with NATIVE support for Ada. But one thing I know for sure is that postgresql with apq (Ada binding to various databases, postgresql among them) should work for you. And it is quite easy to use.

Answer (score 0):

Why not look at MySql? It's one of, if not the, mot popular, free database and certainly not afraid of a piddling 1,000,000 inserts per day ,-)

You will find all that you need with [Gnade](http://gnade.sourceforge.net/).

> The GNADE (GNat Ada Database Environment) project is an open source
>   project with the primary goal to provide all tools and packages
>   necessary to create an Ada 95 development environment providing a
>   seamless integration of relational databases and other database
>   products with Ada 95.
>
> The project provides the following software packages:
>
> ```
> Thin bindings to different RDBMS products like Oracle, PostgreSQL, MySQL  
> using ODBC.
>
> Embedded SQL.
> Native bindings to other RDBMS aproaches such as sqlite
> Object persistency (ODB).
> ```
>
> The ODBC interface has been selected as primary interface to the
>   underlying data base because most of the known DBCS do provide this
>   interface and it is already well understood and established standard.